# send json data to server jquery.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Another json related question unfortunately...

Consider the following json

```
[{"details":{
"forename":"Barack",
"surname":"Obama",
"company":"government",
"email":"bigcheese@whitehouse.com",
"files": [{
      "title":"file1","url":"somefile.pdf"
       },
       {
       "title":"file2",
       "url":"somefile.pdf"
       }]
}
}]
```

I need to send this data to a php script on my server and then interact with it on the server but don't know how.

I'm sending it via jquery.ajax and its being sent fine (no error messages) and heres the code. (newJson is my json object I've created exactly as above)

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "test.php",
dataType: 'json',
data: newJson,
success: function(msg) 
    {
    alert(msg);
    },
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) 
    {
    alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

So in my php script so far I just want to echo back the content as a string which displays in the success alert

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
echo $_POST;
?>
```

but that just gives me a parse error.. so any ideas you wonderful people?

Comment: What's the parse error?

Comment: thats the entire message just parse error - thats the message that appears on the alert

Comment: Just "parse error?" Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your PHP script and see if it tells you more.

Comment: Do a print_r($_POST) or var_dump($_POST)

Comment: have to send key/value pair(s) to php...show us how you create `newjson`. parseerror occurs due to data you send back

Comment: having removed the data type declaration from the jquery ajax request var_dump($_POST) now returns

array(1){[]=>string(0) ""}

Comment: It should also be noted that you're **sending** json to the server and therefore `contentType: application/json` as this tells the server the type of data it is receiving. `dataType` is what you expect to **receive** from the server.

Comment: adding content type brings up an error in chrome "Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have a key/value pair to receive the data in php with `$_POST[key]`. Sending the array you have all by itself is not best approach since you already have structure to object

I would unwrap the outer array, since you are only sending one object inside it

Then Object would look like

```
{"details":{
"forename":"Barack",
"surname":"Obama",
"company":"government",
"email":"bigcheese@whitehouse.com",
"files": [{
      "title":"file1","url":"somefile.pdf"
       },
       {
       "title":"file2",
       "url":"somefile.pdf"
       }]
}
}
```

In php would receive with `$_POST['details']`. Don't convert to JSON, just pass the whole object to `$.ajax data` property.

If you get `parserror` from ajax, is on receiving side and sounds like either getting a 500 eror from php or not sending back json as expected by your `dataType`

Comment: ok so far so good, so how would I access each element for instance how would I create a variable containing the forename? Edit: In php I should add

Comment: `$forenanme= $_POST['details']['forename'];`. WOuld store `$_POST['details']` in variable like `$details` to make it easier `$details['forename'];`

Comment: then can loop over `$details['files']` as regular php array

Comment: yeah like so 

$filesArray = $_POST['details']['files'];

if ($filesArray) {
 foreach ($filesArray as $item) {
  echo $item['title'];
  echo $item['url'];
 }
}

Comment: much appreciated upvoted and answer accepted - thank you very mutch

Answer (score 1):

First, the original JSON string is of wrong format. Try

```
{
  "details":{
    "forename":"Barack",
    "surname":"Obama",
    "company":"government",
    "email":"bigcheese@whitehouse.com",
    "files": [
      { "title":"file1","url":"somefile.pdf" },
      { "title":"file2","url":"somefile.pdf"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Second, the data sent to PHP has already parsed into an array, but not in JSON. To echo, you must use json_encode to convert the array back to JSON string

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
exit;
```

Comment: also a very good answer, but I choose charlietfl's answer as s/he helped me with data manipulation as well..

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not passing the JSON as a field, you can do:

```
<?php 
  $post = file_get_contents("php://input");
  $json = json_decode($post);
  var_dump($json); // Should be a nice object for you.
```